# How to create custom component and add it to flow in spring java dsl?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to create a customer component trace() and want to use it in the flow.

Something like `CustomFlows.from("").trace().get();`

Can you suggest me how to do it? Seems like IntegrationFlowDefinition is closed and not extendable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting technique... But right now I'm not convinced that we should allow such a extension for the `FlowBuilder`...
Feel free to raise [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/39) issue on the matter and we will see in the future how to be with that.

For such an extension you should understand how the Framework works on the background.

Let's consider the simplest component `.bridge()`! Its goal to transfer message from one channel to another. So, this component is of `request-reply` type and must be tied with those two channels on it sides:

```
.channel()
.bridge()
.channel()
```

Of course DSL can create `DirectChannel`s on those places where we don't define explicit one. Or we can rely on the `replyChannel` header, too if we finish our flow with its end - `.get()`. And so on.

The `BridgeHandler` is an out-of-the-box component, that's why we provide the 
explicit DSL method for it.

But from other side it has very simple code:

```
public class BridgeHandler extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler {

    @Override
    public String getComponentType() {
        return "bridge";
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleRequestMessage(Message<?> requestMessage) {
        return requestMessage;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldCopyRequestHeaders() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you see it is a `MessageHandler` implementation, so we can use it directly like this:

```
.handle(new BridgeHandler())
```

From here the question from me to you: what is the reason to bring some complexity to the Framework, if you can reach your requirements with existing features: implement `MessageHandler`, extend `AbstractPayloadTransformer`. Or even just forget about them all and do everything with POJO method invocation, like this since DSL `1.1`:

```
@Override
protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
        return from(this, "messageSource", e -> e.poller(p -> p.trigger(this::nextExecutionTime)))
                .split(this)
                .transform(this)
                .aggregate(a -> a.processor(this, null), null)
                .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("foo", "FOO"))
                .filter(this)
                .handle(this)
                .channel(c -> c.queue("myFlowAdapterOutput"));
    }
```

See my [article](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/spring-integration-java-dsl-1-1-m1-is-available) on the matter.

So, you should find many argument to convince me to extend framework that way :-).

Comment: Thank you sir. We have multiple outbound call gateways. I need to build a convenience method to log whether the call completes successfully or not. We can do this with global interceptor. But thinking is there any other way to do this. Any suggestions are most welcome in this matter?