# How to autowire beans inside a Spring Integration custom message handler?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I wish create a custom message handler to use checkpoints in flows. Besides, those checkpoints will be stored in **ElasticSearch**.

I created a class **Checkpoint**:

```
@Component
public class Checkpoint {

    public static final String TASK_HEADER_KEY = "task";

    public static CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec warn(String message) {
        return new CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec(new CheckpointHandler("WARN", message));
    }
}
// ... methods omitted: error, info etc
```

Next I created **CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec**:

```
public class CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec extends MessageHandlerSpec<CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec, CheckpointHandler> {

    public CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec(CheckpointHandler checkpointHandler) {
        this.target = checkpointHandler;
    }

    public CheckpointMessageHandlerSpec apply(Message<?> message) {
        this.target.handleMessage(message);
        return _this();
    }

    @Override
    protected CheckpointHandler doGet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

**CheckpointHandler**, in this class I wish to inject things, like services or repositories from Spring Data:

```
public class CheckpointHandler extends IntegrationObjectSupport implements MessageHandler {

    private String status;
    private String message;

    // I want inject services or repositories here

    public CheckpointHandler(String status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
        // Test to watch if I have the bean factory. It is always null
        this.getBeanFactory();

        Expression expression = EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("'" + this.message + "'");

        // Here I intend to persist information of payload/headers with spring-data-elasticSearch repository previously injected   
        Object obj = expression.getValue(message);
    }
}
```

Finally, a example of use, inside a flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow checkpointFlow(Checkpoint checkpoint) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("/checkpointFlow"))
            .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(Checkpoint.TASK_HEADER_KEY, taskName))
            .handle(new AppendMessageHandler())
            .wireTap(c -> c.handle(m -> checkpoint.warn("SOMETHING IS HAPPENING HERE. MY PAYLOAD: ' + payload.toString() + '").apply(m)))
            .handle(m -> log.info("[LOGGING DEMO] {}" , m.getPayload()))
            .get();
}

private class AppendMessageHandler implements GenericHandler {

    @Override
    public String handle(Object payload, Map headers) {
        return new StringBuilder().append(testMessage).toString();
    }
}
```

What I miss? Is it possible to do that? I had this idea following this question [How to create custom component and add it to flow in spring java dsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626497/how-to-create-custom-component-and-add-it-to-flow-in-spring-java-dsl)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bean can be autowired, if they are, well, exactly beans.

Let take a look into your code one more time!

```
c.handle(m -> checkpoint.warn("SOMETHING IS HAPPENING HERE. MY PAYLOAD: ' + payload.toString() + '").apply(m))
```

The real bean here is exactly Lambda :). Sad, of course, but not your custom factory with subsequent `apply()`. Your custom code is invoked exactly in the target Lambda for each incoming message, but without aware about `BeanFactory`.

To fix your problem you should use your factory as is:

```
.wireTap(c -> c.handle(checkpoint.warn("SOMETHING IS HAPPENING HERE. MY PAYLOAD: ' + payload.toString() + '")))
```

And Framework will take care about registration your `CheckpointHandler` as a bean and, therefore, autowiring.

AS you may guess already you don't need that `apply()` method. Just because there is need to distinguish *assemble* phase when Java DSL populates a tree for beans. The initialization and registration phase, when that tree is parsed by the Framework and beans are registered in the application context. And, finally, there is a runtime phase, when messages are travel from channel to channel though all those message handler, transformers etc.